# Help with a particular Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation in question is a FODE,

$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{a^2\sqrt{2g}}{\sqrt{(R+y)(R-y)}}
$$

Upon first inspection, this is separable, but I don't know how to proceed from there.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you check I edited your question correctly? Also, what is a FODE?

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Just integrate $\sqrt{(R-y) (R+y)}$ with respect to $y$ after having set $dt=...dy$. You will have a nice first change of variable such as $y=R x$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{a^2\sqrt{2g}}{\sqrt{(R+y)(R-y)}}
$$
is indeed seperable
$$
\int\sqrt{R^{2}-y^{2}}dy = -a^{2}\sqrt{2g}t + \lambda
$$
using $y=R\cos\theta$ leads to
$$
\int R\sin\theta d\left(R\cos\theta\right) = -\int R^2\sin^{2}\theta d\theta = -a^{2}\sqrt{2g}t + \lambda
$$
Do you need this to be completed?

$\textbf{Edit:}$
The question was actually meant to be 
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{a^2\sqrt{2g}}{\sqrt{(R+y)}(R-y)}
$$
This is not too bad (it is actually easier), and is instead separated as
$$
\int\sqrt{R+y}(R-y)dy = -a^{2}\sqrt{2g}t + \lambda
$$
with the substitution $v=R+y$
$$
\int v^{1/2}\left(2R-v\right)dv = -a^{2}\sqrt{2g}t + \lambda
$$

This is all assuming $R=$constant.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I made an error in submission, i had meant to express sqrt(R+y)*(R-y).

Comment: ok, I think you need to update the edits that @enzotib made :).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!